# Which config approach is more flexible and common for a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby

Say, you were to create a gem which had to be configured. When would you choose this approach?

```
  MyGem.configure do |config|
      config.var1 = 123
      config.var2 = "something"
  end
```

and when this?

```
# my_gem.yml
var1: 123
var2: "something"
```

And when perphaps both of them?

Which is more flexible/common/recommended/de-facto?

Comment: Please do not undo helpful edits to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

I prefer

```
MyGem.new(123, 'something')
```

So I can use the Gem with multiple configurations.